# How to customize the QGIS GUI using Python?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, gui

Is it possible to hide/remove/customize the default UI of QGIS from a Python plugin?

I want to add my own menus and toolbars and remove some included by default in QGIS.

If it's possible, which reference should I use?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it's possible to customize the QGIS UI from a Python plugin by both adding your own toolbars and  menus as well as removing/hiding QGIS toolbars and menus.

These would be the code snippets for each situation:

1. Adding a toolbar:

   ```
   # Add a custom toolbar
   self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar( "My tools" )
   self.toolbar.setObjectName( "My tools" )
   self.toolbar.addAction( self.action )
   ```
2. Removing a QGIS toolbar:

   ```
   # Remove a QGIS toolbar (e.g., the File toolbar)
   fileToolBar = self.iface.fileToolBar()
   self.iface.mainWindow().removeToolBar( fileToolBar )
   ```
3. Adding a menu:

   ```
   # Add a custom menu
   self.menu = QMenu( "&My tools", self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar() )
   self.menu.setObjectName( "&My tools" )
   actions = self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar().actions()
   lastAction = actions[-1]
   self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar().insertMenu( lastAction, self.menu )
   self.menu.addAction( self.action )
   ```
4. Removing a QGIS menu:

   ```
   # Remove a QGIS menu (e.g., the Edit menu)
   editMenu = self.iface.editMenu()
   editMenu.menuAction().setVisible( False )
   ```

You can append such code to the `initGui()` method of your plugin. I assumed you have an action created in such method, as any plugin has.

You can see these code snippets implemented in a test plugin that I've created and [published here](https://github.com/gacarrillor/test/tree/qgis_gui_customization). In the README file you find instructions for both installing and using it.

---

*Note: You can get a reference of QGIS menus and toolbars from Python by using methods exposed by `iface`. A list of such methods can be found in the [QGIS docs](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html).*

Comment: nice code snippets.just one note to code snippet 3:If you reload the plugin(with plugin reloader for example) you will always get one more of your custom menus. but i fixed it with the help of one other answer of you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169869/adding-multiple-plugins-to-custom-menu-in-qgis

Answer (score 2):

open .ui file with QT Designer or QT Creator and follow QT guides.
Other QGIS oriented references are:
PyQGIS Programmers's Guide - https://locatepress.com/ppg
and some more Packt books in publishing

Comment: I wanna do it using python plugin. don't wanna modify qgis ui file

Comment: latest version of plugin builder use onthefly compiling of .ui file so you don't have is compiled in as .py.
Just go in <your plugin>_dialog.py and remove FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType... with import to your .ui compilation
.ui compilation can be done manually with pyuic4 -o outfile.py <your ui file>

Comment: after compilation you'll have a .py that you can modify manually using pyqt as usual