# QGIS toolbars source code

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, toolbar

I can see the source code of the core QGIS plugins from the repository in github. But is there any repository of source codes for QGIS toolbars also?

Comment: Perhaps this might help: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/gui/qgisinterface.h

Comment: The above link helps somewhat but still whether GUI's in QGIS are being developed only by C++? Source code in python would help me much better.

Comment: Hopefully others can advise on this issue as it is beyond my scope :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean QGIS default toolbars, well, those are written in C++ and you can find their creation and configuration [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/app/qgisapp.cpp#L1485) (C++ file) and [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/ui/qgisapp.ui#L375) (Qt4 UI file). All actions (buttons) inside QGIS toolbars are written in C++ (except by plugin buttons) and you can find them in the QGIS source code as well.

If you want to get a reference of a QGIS toolbar in Python, you should use the `iface` object (instance of [QgisInterface](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html)), which exposes QGIS toolbars. For example, have a look at [How to customize the QGIS GUI using Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127150/how-to-customize-the-qgis-default-gui-using-python/132238#132238), where I explain how to customize the QGIS GUI (menus and toolbars) via Python.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had got an enough idea from the link.