# Adding multiple plugins to custom menu in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am new to Python and QGIS and attempting to create some plugins to replicate in-house tools used in other GIS programs. I have added a custom menu using Python and added the plugin to the menu using the following code within the `initGui` method:

```
self.menu = QMenu("&Menu Name", self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar())
actions = self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar().actions()
lastAction = actions[-1]
self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar().insertMenu(lastAction,self.menu)
self.action = QAction(QIcon(":/plugins/Trial/icon.png"),"Trial plugin", self.iface.mainWindow())
self.action.triggered.connect(self.run)
self.menu.addAction(self.action)
```

However, if I try and add another plugin to the same menu I end up with duplicated menu item names with only one plugin in the menu, rather than all the plugins under the same menu. Is there a way of adding multiple plugins to an existing custom menu item?

Comment: global name 'QMenu' is not defined

Comment: I am getting the same issue - "QMenu is not defined" when I add this and the code below into a working plugin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a way. You need to check whether your menu is already present in the QGIS Menu Bar. If so, you can reuse it, otherwise, you create it.

In the `initGui` method of each of your plugins, add the following code (see comments for details):

```
# Check if the menu exists and get it
self.menu = self.iface.mainWindow().findChild( QMenu, '&My tools' )

# If the menu does not exist, create it!
if not self.menu:
    self.menu = QMenu( '&My tools', self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar() )
    self.menu.setObjectName( '&My tools' )
    actions = self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar().actions()
    lastAction = actions[-1]
    self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar().insertMenu( lastAction, self.menu )

# Finally, add your action to the menu
self.menu.addAction( self.action )
```

Comment: Carrillo - I am getting the same issue - "QMenu is not defined" when I add this into a working plugin. Is there somewhere this should be defined?

Comment: Chances are you're missing the QMenu import. For QGIS v3.x: `from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QMenu`

Comment: How would you go about not removing both plugins when calling *self.iface.removePluginMenu* in the unload method?

Comment: I think you would need to check if you're the last plugin left in the menu and only then remove it.

Comment: I create menu bar as mentioned above but when I reloading its creating another menu how to Unload the menu bar. please provide code snippet