# Creating menu item and adding more than 1 plugin in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

Because if I execute these lines for each plugin, I created a menu item for each plugin.

I created many plugins and wish to place them in a new menu item (not traditionals)

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Adding multiple plugins to custom menu in QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169869/adding-multiple-plugins-to-custom-menu-in-qgis)