# How to group my plugins in QGIS menu and toolbar?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, toolbar

I work on and test more QGIS plugins which falls into the same category (lets call it MyProcessing). Though they fall into the same category I want to keep them as separate plugins. I would like to have these plugins in the **Plugins menu** sharing same menu item (My Processing) and especially sharing the same toolbar (separate from standard plugin toolbar). Is there a way to do that?

In one plugin I create toolbar in interface:

```
self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'MyProcessing')
self.toolbar.setObjectName(u'MyProcessing')
```

How do I check in other plugin if toolbar *MyProcessing* exists and add icon into it?

Same with the menu item, is there a way to check if menu item already exists and add other plugin action into it?

Comment: Seems for the same menu item there is already answer http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169869/adding-multiple-plugins-to-custom-menu-in-qgis?rq=1 so I am especially interested in sharing the toolbar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `findChild` method of QGIS `mainWindow` to know if there is a `QToolBar` called `u'MyProcessing'` and get it. If you don't get anything, create it.

```
myToolBar = iface.mainWindow().findChild( QToolBar, u'MyProcessing' )
if not myToolBar:
    myToolBar = iface.addToolBar( u'MyProcessing' )
    myToolBar.setObjectName( u'MyProcessing' )
```

This needs to be checked in each of your plugins. You can then use `myToolBar` to add actions and perhaps a separator to visually group actions (buttons) for each plugin:

```
myToolBar.addAction( 'A' )
myToolBar.addAction( 'B' )
myToolBar.addSeparator()
myToolBar.addAction( 'C' )
```

As you pointed out, reusing menus is explained here: [Adding multiple plugins to custom menu in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/169880/4972)

Comment: Aha! So the only difference between finding item in menu and item in toolbar is using  QToolBar or QMenu in findChild(). Thank you :)