# Grouping Custom Plugins using Python QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

UPDATE: Pasted the whole code.

I am developing a QGS project and im in the process of removing menus and grouping the plugins I have created (using PluginBuilder). So far I have 3 plugins and I want to group them in a single Tools menu.

This question might have been answered already by the post [Adding multiple plugins to custom menu in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169869/adding-multiple-plugins-to-custom-menu-in-qgis/169880#169880) but it doesn't seem to work though I copied the whole code in the answer. I get the error **"AttributeError: FindFarm instance has no attribute 'action' "** Below is my code in my plugin:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
/***************************************************************************
 FindFarm
                                 A QGIS plugin
 Find and zoom to a farm
                              -------------------
        begin                : 2017-09-29
        git sha              : $Format:%H$
        copyright            : (C) 2017 by William Ernesto Jr
        email                : williamcernestojr@yahoo.com
 ***************************************************************************/

/***************************************************************************
 *                                                                         *
 *   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify  *
 *   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by  *
 *   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or     *
 *   (at your option) any later version.                                   *
 *                                                                         *
 ***************************************************************************/
"""
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
# Initialize Qt resources from file resources.py
import resources
# Import the code for the dialog
from find_farm_dialog import FindFarmDialog
from qgis.core import *
import os.path


class FindFarm:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor.

        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
            which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
            application at run time.
        :type iface: QgsInterface
        """
        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # initialize locale
        locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
        locale_path = os.path.join(
            self.plugin_dir,
            'i18n',
            'FindFarm_{}.qm'.format(locale))

        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)

            if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
                QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)

        # Create the dialog (after translation) and keep reference
        self.dlg = FindFarmDialog()

        # Declare instance attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.menu = self.tr(u'&FindFarm')
        # TODO: We are going to let the user set this up in a future iteration
        self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'FindFarm')
        self.toolbar.setObjectName(u'FindFarm')

        self.iface.mapCanvas().clear()
        self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()

    # noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
    def tr(self, message):
        """Get the translation for a string using Qt translation API.

        We implement this ourselves since we do not inherit QObject.

        :param message: String for translation.
        :type message: str, QString

        :returns: Translated version of message.
        :rtype: QString
        """
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker,PyArgumentList,PyCallByClass
        return QCoreApplication.translate('FindFarm', message)


    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):
        """Add a toolbar icon to the toolbar.

        :param icon_path: Path to the icon for this action. Can be a resource
            path (e.g. ':/plugins/foo/bar.png') or a normal file system path.
        :type icon_path: str

        :param text: Text that should be shown in menu items for this action.
        :type text: str

        :param callback: Function to be called when the action is triggered.
        :type callback: function

        :param enabled_flag: A flag indicating if the action should be enabled
            by default. Defaults to True.
        :type enabled_flag: bool

        :param add_to_menu: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the menu. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_menu: bool

        :param add_to_toolbar: Flag indicating whether the action should also
            be added to the toolbar. Defaults to True.
        :type add_to_toolbar: bool

        :param status_tip: Optional text to show in a popup when mouse pointer
            hovers over the action.
        :type status_tip: str

        :param parent: Parent widget for the new action. Defaults None.
        :type parent: QWidget

        :param whats_this: Optional text to show in the status bar when the
            mouse pointer hovers over the action.

        :returns: The action that was created. Note that the action is also
            added to self.actions list.
        :rtype: QAction
        """

        # Create the dialog (after translation) and keep reference
        self.dlg = FindFarmDialog()

        icon = QIcon(icon_path)
        action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
        action.triggered.connect(callback)
        action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)

        if status_tip is not None:
            action.setStatusTip(status_tip)

        if whats_this is not None:
            action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)

        if add_to_toolbar:
            self.toolbar.addAction(action)

        if add_to_menu:
            self.iface.addPluginToDatabaseMenu(
                self.menu,
                action)

        self.actions.append(action)

        return action

    def initGui(self):
        """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

        icon_path = ':/plugins/FindFarm/icon.png'
        self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(u'Find Farm'),
            callback=self.run,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow())
        # Check if the menu exists and get it
        self.menu = self.iface.mainWindow().findChild( QMenu, '&My tools' )

        # If the menu does not exist, create it!
        if not self.menu:
            self.menu = QMenu( '&Tools', self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar() )
            self.menu.setObjectName( '&Tools' )
            actions = self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar().actions()
            lastAction = actions[-1]
            self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar().insertMenu( lastAction, self.menu )

        # Finally, add your action to the menu
        self.menu.addAction( self.action )


    def unload(self):
        """Removes the plugin menu item and icon from QGIS GUI."""
        for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginDatabaseMenu(
                self.tr(u'&FindFarm'),
                action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)
        # remove the toolbar
        del self.toolbar


    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""
        self.iface.mapCanvas().clear()
        self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh() 
        for lyr in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
            print "Layer is ", lyr.name()
            if lyr.name() == "Farm Extents":
                layer = lyr
                self.iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
                farmname = layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex( 'ATT_FARM_FieldGrp_CODE' )
                uv = layer.dataProvider().uniqueValues( farmname )
                self.dlg.comboBox.clear()
                self.dlg.comboBox.addItems( uv )
                # show the dialog
                self.dlg.show()
                break
        else:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(), "Error", "Could not find a layer named 'Farm Extents'")
            return   

        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            fname = self.dlg.comboBox.currentText()
            QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable('farm_name',fname)
            #l = self.iface.mapCanvas().layers()['Farm Extents']
            expr = QgsExpression( "\"ATT_FARM_FieldGrp_CODE\"='" + fname + "'")
            it = layer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest( expr ) )
            ids = [i.id() for i in it]
            layer.setSelectedFeatures( ids )
            self.iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()
            print "Zoomed in to", fname
```

I'm new to python.

Comment: I think it would be better to paste the complete Class... The error is in the last line - that means that your class doesnt have a (class) variable self.action. So - without seeing from what the class inherits or what happens in the constructor/__init__-function its hard to say...

Comment: it's look like an indentation problem or it's due to the copy/past ? please change this to your post

Comment: I have updated the post to include everything. Thank you.

Comment: HugoRoussaffa-GeoDatup indentation is faulty in my post since I have only copied that part of the code. Kindly take a look at the updated code. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `initGui()` function, you did not define `action`. Try replacing

```
self.menu.addAction( self.action )
```

with something like the following (edit to fit your requirements):

```
self.menu.addAction(QIcon(':/plugins/FindFarm/icon_2.png'), "Find something", self.myFunction)
```

Comment: @WilliamErnesto - Most welcome! Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

change your indentation like follow,  cause in your post the init_gui method doesn't know your code

```
def initGui(self):

    """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

    icon_path = ':/plugins/FindFarm/icon.png'
    self.add_action(
        icon_path,
        text=self.tr(u'Find Farm'),
        callback=self.run,
        parent=self.iface.mainWindow())
    # Check if the menu exists and get it
    self.menu = self.iface.mainWindow().findChild( QMenu, '&My tools' )

    # If the menu does not exist, create it!
    if not self.menu:
        self.menu = QMenu( '&Tools', self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar() )
        self.menu.setObjectName( '&Tools' )
        actions = self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar().actions()
        lastAction = actions[-1]
        self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar().insertMenu( lastAction, self.menu )

    # Finally, add your action to the menu
    self.menu.addAction( self.action )
```