# Adding multiple plugins to custom menu in QGIS3

Tags: pyqgis

I have a set of Plugins that I have to restructure according to different sub menus in a Global Menu. For the moment, I have two plugins but each time it recreates the menu for me while I integrate the second plugin directly on the Global menu as the first plugin to Create.

```
class ClassGeneraleMenu:
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        # Declaration de mon Menu Global en premier lieu
        self.ambition_menu = QtWidgets.QMenu('MenuGlobal')

    # Function qui me crée des sous menus dans ma MenuGlobal
    def atrqgis_add_submenu(self, submenu):
        self.ambition_menu.addMenu(submenu)

    # Function iniGuit
    def initGui(self):
        # Insertion du Menu dans la barre menu de Qgis
        self.iface.mainWindow().menuBar().insertMenu(self.iface.firstRightStandardMenu().menuAction(),self.ambition_menu)

        # Sous Menu Par projet
        # Myprojet Sous Menu
        self.adn_menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(QCoreApplication.translate("atrqgis", "&Myprojet"))
        self.atrqgis_add_submenu(self.adn_menu)
        
        # CONTROLE DESIGN Submenu
        self.controle_design = self.adn_menu.addMenu('Contrôle')

        # Ajout des actions dans dans la fenetre execution
        icon = QIcon(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/icons/import.png")
        self.animate_lines_action = QtWidgets.QAction(icon, "A.1.1 Import de données", self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.animate_lines_action.triggered.connect(self.baba_fonc)
        
        # Ajout de l'action dans la CONTROLE DESIGN Submenu
        self.controle_design.addAction(self.animate_lines_action)
```

This example is the same for all my Plugins, except that I want each Plugin to insert into an existing menu

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169869/adding-multiple-plugins-to-custom-menu-in-qgis/169880#169880

Comment: If a create a first plugin with the Menu Bar "MenuGlobal", i can't see this Menu in my second Plugin created. This script `code` test = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QMenu, 'MenuGlobal')
print(test) `code` return None in the seconde Plugin

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the menu's object name?